# Change the Value of Dynamically Loaded Hidden Form Element

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having trouble changing a value of a hidden form element that was dynamically loaded via ajax. When a user clicks on a date, I'd like a few hidden input fields to get automatically updated with the day, month, and year (only day is shown in the code for simplification).

I suppose the main question is how can I select an element that has been dynamically loaded via ajax.

Simplified Code:

**index.php**

```
<a href="#" id="someLink">Click Me</a>
```

**include.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#someLink').click(function(){
        // Create modal dialog dynamically
        var modal = $('<div/>').attr({
            id:'new' + objectName + 'Modal',
            class:'modal hide fade',
            tabindex:'-1',
            role:'dialog',
        });

        // Ajax call to load modal
        $.ajax({
            url: "getModal.php",
        }).done(function ( data ) {
            modal.html(data);
        });

        // show form
        modal.modal('show');    

        return false;
    });

    // bind datepicker from jQuery UI to text input
    $("body").on({
        focus: function(){ 
             $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                    var inputName = $(this).attr("name"); //returns "startDate"
                    console.log($('#'+inputName+'_day')); // returns "[]"
                    $('#'+inputName+'_day').val(new Date(dateText).getDate());
                  }
            });
        }
    },'.datepicker');
});
```

**getModal.php**

```
echo <?php
echo "<form name='modalForm'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='startDate_day' id='startDate_day'>";
echo "<input type='text' class='datepicker' name='startDate' id='startDate'>";
echo "</form>";
echo ?>
```

Comment: Where is `inputName` defined? I can find only usages and no definition in your code

Comment: As far as i can see there is nothing to do with your ajax loading, it's not the point. You just select DOM element as usual and change it. And `console.log('#'+inputName+'_day') => []` - this can't be true, `[]` can be returned by jQuery wrapper, not by concat of strings

Comment: I added the line that now shows where the inputName came from.

Comment: jQuery doesn't lies to you, you have no element with `id` equals `startDate_day`

Comment: Sorry for that error, I've corrected the post. In my webapp, there is indeed an id equal to "startDate_day".

Comment: This can't be true =) I don't believe you. jQuery will return you element by `id` if it is present in DOM, if not - you should look in debugger more closely on your selector string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the cause of the issue which I'm hoping will help someone else.

I use Grails/Rails and which automatically put a period character in the ID and I overlooked this. I was subsequently trying to use jQuery to call an element with a period in the name which will not work (because periods are reserved for class names).

I did create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucaL/12/) showing the details in this question working successfully.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no issues with how DOM element was loaded, if it present - jQuery will find it.

You should select your element by `name` selector

```
$('input[name="' + inputName + '"_day"]').val(...);
```

or give your loaded input an `id="startDate_day"`

Answer (score 0):

You may use Chrome console or Firebug to try the following the snippet.

```
console.log(inputName);
$('#'+inputName+'_day').val();
```

There must exists an element with that name otherwise jQuery wont be able to return you anything.

Just as another debugging technique, you may try search the word "form" in page view source to see if your desired form has been loaded or not.

Comment: As far as i understand, form is showed properly and there is a date picker, whose callback actually not works